# Is there an alternative Visual Studio keyboard shortcut for ToggleHeaderCodeFile which works for jumping to a C++ module interface file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, c++-modules

When working with header files and cpp files I am usually jumping around the code by using the Visual Studio shortcut `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ToggleHeaderCodeFile`, however this doesn't seem to work for jumping between a `.ixx` module interface file and a `.cpp` implementation file.

Is there an alternative keyboard shortcut in visual studio that I am missing? Or has it not been implemented yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Toggle Header/Code File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/navigate-code-cpp?view=msvc-170#toggle-headercode-file)

`You can switch between a header file and its corresponding source file.`

According to the description, I'm afraid currently the feature you need is not supported. You could use F12 and Ctrl+F12 as an alternative. And report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp), then post the link here so that we can follow up.

Comment: Thanks, I have logged a feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Keyboard-Shortcut-for-jumping-between-mo/10532215